# Codeigniter cannot search database in some char

Tags: php, codeigniter

I trying to use active records codeigniter and also custom query with a lot of loop data but error undefined in some string, but for another its working fine.

This is my helper code

```
function getDealerList($link)
{   
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->db->select('*');
$CI->db->from('dealer_list');
$CI->db->like('link',$link);
$query = $CI->db->get();
$data = $query->result();
return $data[0]->id_dealer;
}
```

and i call from my controller like this

```
echo getDealerList('bsb-swiss-watches-(albert-mazloum-and-son)');
```

And displaying error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset: 0 Filename: helpers/web_helper.php Line Number: 51

I assume there some of string containing "(" or ")" that make my script error.

Can somebody help to fix this bugs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$query->result()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

```
This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.
```

You need to get data using `row_array()`

**HELPER**

```
function getDealerList($link) {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->db->select('*');
    $CI->db->from('dealer_list');
    $CI->db->like('link', $link);
    $query = $CI->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row_array();

        return $row['id_dealer'];
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your function and now it will work. please check.

```
function getDealerList($link)
{
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->db->select('*');
$CI->db->from('dealer_list');
$name = $link;
$CI->db->like('link', $link);
$query = $CI->db->get();
$data = $query->result_array();
return $data[0]->id_dealer;
}
```